# Teams chat bot on bot framework incorrectly sends files

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

colleagues.

We have some issue with Teams workflow.

We use Microsoft Bot Framework for sending files from Sharepoint to users in Tenant. We use `FileInfoCard` for sending files as message attachments from bot to user and user can open this attachment in teams like usual file. But two or three weeks ago this functionality was broken and now Teams shows us a that message: "This item may be missing or unavailable.
The item may have been deleted, its expired or permission to view it is missing. Additional information can be obtained from its owner". 
This problem shows only on desktop and web clients, but on mobile client it works fine.

What problem it can be?

Comment: Can you paste or link to the relevant code in your bot?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/dFQxBGzG I changed information in links for example and independent cases, but this example shows the present logic, which doesn't works after last Teams update.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything wrong in your code and your issue appears to be related to a Teams update, so I'll edit out the botframework tag. I know there's a couple MS Teams support guys that frequent SO, so they should be able to help. If not, here's their support page: https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public

Comment: @MaximEremin- Tried your code snippet and it's working fine. How are you fetching the SharePoint file link? Also, you mentioned that for older files it's showing error, what happens if you send new file?

Comment: Also, if you are still facing issue with new files, could you please once try sending .txt file?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT we tried to generate new link for files and tried to upload new files and generate the new links for them.


For getting link we generate sharing link on SharePoint Online, on some back-end we get the real link to the file with GuID using SharePoint CSOM (.NET) and on bot backend we attach file as file information.

Comment: Did sending a new file worked from bot?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT No, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I will clarify - we use Bot Framework 3rd version.

Comment: Let's try the [files send receive sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-files#basic-example-in-c) which simply sends back the file you just uploaded to bot. Can you confirm if this is working for you?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT it works, yes. What advice can you give for parsing SharePoint links? I think, it is a problem with parsing links by Teams - it can break links in the parse moment, because it worked fine sometime ago. For example, link:

h ttps://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SITE/_layouts/15/ Doc.aspx ?sourcedoc={GUID}&file=NAME.docx

Comment: I was able to send file info card with exactly same URL format. Can you confirm that your GUID in link and UniqueId are same? For testing you can manually get SharePoint link for a file in Microsoft Teams.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I confirm that my GUID in link and UniqueID are same. I copied link of file from teams and successfully opened it in browser, but this file doesn't open in teams like file on Desktop client. But one moment - if I click on button "Edit in teams" it will be opened in Teams in PowerPoint Online Wrapper.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I think, I found a problem!

When I send file with link from sharepoint like FileInfo, teams makes the sharing link with broken property sourcedoc. The link looks like h ttps://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SITE/_layouts/15/ Doc.aspx?OR=teams&CT=1550917298225&action=edit&sourcedoc={{GUID}}


If you see, the sourcedoc property frames with double brackets. If I want to open the file in Word/PowerPoint/Excel Online it shows me a error message. But if I delete extra brackets in link in browser - it works fine! I think it's a bug in a new version

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT hello! Any something adds?

Comment: Checking this internally. Btw, do you have code snippet of how you fetch/create SharePoint document link?

Comment: @MaximEremin we have never seen the double brackets: can you show us the code that generates links with double brackets?